# I want to create my own tail command with using getline and wihout use of lseek and fseek

Tags: c, linux, tail

I implemented below code but i want tailbuf[] should be in order. I want tailbuf[9] should be last line, tailbuf[8] second and so on. Please help me how i cant implement that in this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char ** lastnumlines(FILE *fp, unsigned int num)   
{
  int count = num;
  int n, i, iNo1 = 0, iNo2= 0,z = 0;
  size_t MAXSIZE = 1024;
  char **tailbuf=calloc(count, sizeof(char *));

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
  {
    tailbuf[i] = calloc(MAXSIZE, sizeof(char));
  }

  while (getline(&tailbuf[iNo2], &MAXSIZE, fp) != EOF)
  {
     iNo2 = (iNo2 + 1) % count;
     if (iNo2 == iNo1) 
     {
        iNo1 = (iNo1 + 1) % count; 
     }
  }

 i = iNo2;
 int k = 0;
 do{ 
     printf("%s\n",tailbuf[i]);
     i = (i+1) % count;            
   }while (i != iNo2);


   free(tailbuf);    
 }

int main()
{
  char *filename = "demo1.txt";
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");

  if(fp == NULL)
  {
     printf("Unable to open file!\n");
     exit(1);
  }

  lastnumlines(fp,10);    
  fclose(fp);   
  return 0;
}
```

How i can tailbuf in order?

Comment: Why don’t you you iNo1 , and what the use of k. You must remember that iNo2 correspond to num-1  in tailbuf

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution should be to have two arrays of lines pointers (note that the memory won't be duplicated)

- a circular buffer to read the file without other difficulty than using a mod op `%`
- a linear buffer reordering the read line to be used elsewhere:

```c
void lastnumlines(FILE *fp, unsigned int num)   
{
    /* variable names have been made more expressive */

    int i; 
    size_t size = 1024;
    char **tailbuf=calloc(num, sizeof(char *));
    char **circbuf=calloc(num, sizeof(char *));
    
    int index_in_buff = 0;
    int line_no = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        circbuf[i] = malloc(size);
    }

    /* get lines in circular buffer */
    while (getline(&circbuf[index_in_buff % num], &size, fp) != EOF)
    {
        ++index_in_buff;
        ++line_no;
    }

    /* reorder lines from circular to linear buffer */
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        printf("%d --> %d\n", (line_no+i)%num, i);
        tailbuf[i] = circbuf[(line_no+i)%num];
    } 

    /* display lines, warning, some may be null if num > line_no */
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        if (tailbuf[i])
            printf("%s", tailbuf[i]);
    }

    /* cleanup memory */
    for (i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        free(tailbuf[i]);
    }

    free(tailbuf);    
    free(circbuf);    
}
```

Note that the `circbuf` can be deleted at the end of function, and `tailbuf` can be returned to be used in other functions. Both `tailbuf` and `circbuf` point to line memory, but there is no deep bind.

Comment: I dont want to travel twice nor open file twice.

Comment: It's not the case, it's read one in `circbuff`, then the (pointers of) lines of `circbuff` are reindexed in `tailbuff`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of how you could do this with a single array of pointers.

Up to 10 lines populate pArr pointers, then `memmove` will "scroll-up" the array so that the 'next' read is always to the final pointer.

```
const int n = 10; // Want last 10 lines. (fewer if short input).
char *pArr[ n ];

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    pArr[ i ] = calloc( 128, sizeof(char) );

int lcnt = 0, retCode = 0;
while( retCode != EOF ) {
    if( lcnt == n - 1 ) {
        char *hold = pArr[0];
        memmove( pArr, pArr + 1, (n - 1) * sizeof(pArr[0]) );
        pArr[ lcnt ] = hold;
    }
    retCode = getline( pArr[ lcnt ], size, fp );
    if( ++lcnt == n )
        lcnt--;
}

for( i = 0; i <= lcnt; i++ )
    printf( ... );

for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    free( pArr[ i ] );
```